# how to keep a totem app always in the foreground?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, root

I have a demand for a product, but I don't know where to start to research it.
The idea is to create an app for a totem of an establishment.
It should always be in the foreground and the customer should not have any way to leave this view.
Besides when I open the OS he should already open the app.

Does anyone have any idea how I can follow this idea?

App for android.

Comment: You can't without a rooted device.

Comment: but to achieve this behavior, would it be via application code or configuration via root? @m0skit0

Comment: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode